# Table Attribute Not Being Used

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am using the table attribute to change the table name so instead of querying the Books table, which is the default, it will look for the BookList table.

```
    <Table(Name:="BookList")>
    Public Class Book
        <Key()>
        Public Property ID() As Integer
    End Class
```

However, when I run the program and try to get the first record, it produces the error:

```
    Invalid object name 'dbo.Books'
```

How do I map the Book class to the BookList table?

Answer (score 1):

You can use EntityTypeConfiguration class to map your table.

```
public class Book_Mapping : EntityTypeConfiguration<Book>
{
    public Book_Mapping()
    {
        HasKey(x => x.Id);

        ToTable("BookList");

        // etc.
    }
}
public class EntitiesContext : DbContext
{
    public EntitiesContext()
        : base("defaultConnection")
    {

    }

    public DbSet<Book> Books { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new Book_Mapping());
    }
}
```